# Setting the height of a SELECT in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

IE seems to ignore the height set in CSS when rendering a HTML SELECT. Are there any work around's for this or do we have to just accept IE will not look as good as other browsers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no work-around for this aside from ditching the `select` element.

Comment: This is correct as far as I can tell for plain vanilla IE7.

Emulators and testers may differ, but using both Virtual Machines and real antique computers I can't make this work. You're right.

Waste not your time with the ton of other stuff on SO which is wrong or misleading.

Answer (score 16):

It is correct that there is no work-around for this aside from ditching the select element, but if you only need to show more items in your select list you can simply use the size attribute:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="15">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

Doing this you'll have additional empty lines if your collection of items lenght is smaller than size value.

Answer (score 7):

you can use a combination of font-size and line-height to force it to go larger, but obviously only in the situations where you need the font larger too

edit:

Example -> <strike>http://www.bse.co.nz</strike> **EDIT: (this link is no longer relevant)**

the select next to the big search box has the following css rules:

```
#navigation #search .locationDrop {
    font-size:2em;
    line-height:27px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:27px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: font-weight can also have an effect. "font-weight: bold;" was having a positive effect for me without even realizing it (until I removed it today and found this article ;)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

I was able to set the height of my `SELECT` to exactly what I wanted in IE8 and 9.  The trick is to set the `box-sizing` property to `content-box`. Doing so will set the content area of the `SELECT` to the height, but keep in mind that `margin`, `border` and `padding` values will not be calculated in the width/height of the `SELECT`, so adjust those values accordingly.

```
select {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fkgg/2/). Would you mind confirming and marking the appropriate answer?

Comment: That fiddle won't even open in IE7.

Comment: Same here for IE8, fiddle can't be loaded properly... Between i have tested it and it didn't worked...

Answer (score 3):

Use a UI library, like [jquery](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxexamplebasic.aspx) or [yui](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html), that provides an alternative to the native SELECT element, typically as part of the implementation of a combo box.

Comment: I use jquery. Can anyone point to a good SELECT replacement that works with jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Even though setting a CSS ***height*** value to the ***select*** element does not work, the ***padding*** attribute works alright. Setting a top and bottom padding will make your ***select*** element look taller.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found in http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/09/setting-height-selectbox-combobox-ie.html
a simple solution (at least for IE8):

```
font-size:      1.0em;
```

BTW, for Google Chrome, found this workaround at
[How to standardize the height of a select box between Chrome and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547354/how-to-increase-the-height-of-the-select-box) */

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a work-around for this (at least for multi-select):

- set select **size** attribute to option list size (use JavaScript or set it to any large enough number)
- set select **max-height** instead of **height** attribute to desired height (tested on IE9)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a replacement: [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). It looks pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

```
select{
  *zoom: 1.6;
  *font-size: 9px;
}
```

If you change properties, size of `select` will change also in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

See also [inconsistent box model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450587/inconsistent-box-model-between-input-typesubmit-and-input-typetext#answer-1450649) between input, select, ...

Answer (score 1):

you could do similar to what facebook does, just add padding around. It is not as good as one could wish but looks reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this was a question not about the height of a 'multiple' type of select element but a drop-down type of select element.  I have come across times when the drop-down looks squashed and does not show clearly the selected value.  Undoubtedly it has to do with CSS style info in use on the page.  The only way to stop it is either change the CSS (which would likely affect the whole page or parts of it in ways you don't want affected) or use style info in the select element itself to override the CSS that's clobbering it.  Example:

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect" style="font-size:15px; height:30px">
<option value="someval">somedescr</option>
...
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to set the height of the select box to be smaller than the default. i used

```
select {
   position: relative;
   height: 10px !important;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

this works on ie7 and ie8. you might only need the `height` property, i just added the `position` and `display` to override properties inherited from higher up the dom.