# input width vs textarea width

Tags: html, css

After reading the thread
[Input size vs width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480588/input-size-vs-width)

I'm clear that we should not use size attribute but css style.

What will be the cross browser css that shows exactly same width for both input[text] and textarea?

BTB, I tried

```
#idInputText, #idTextArea {
font: inherit;
width: 60ex;
```

}

Is it correct? any better solution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native padding for text input elements differ. You will need to assign a different width to input elements and textarea elements and experiment.

```
#form input.textfield { width:10em; }
#form textarea { width:9em; }
```

Just throw some default styles ( I prefer ems ) and pop open Firebug and experiment by changing the size values.

I usually throw a `class=textfield` on `<input type=text>` so I don't target `<input type=submit>` or similar.

Comment: Note that you can target `input[type="text"]`, as well, to avoid styling submit buttons (though it doesn't work with IE6).

Answer (score 2):

You will probably get more consistent results with different browsers by applying a CSS reset first. This article lists some good examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Once you have eliminated the subtle browser differences on padding and margins, then your master width of 60ex should allow the inputs to line up.

Comment: Sadly, that question was removed, but this links to www.css-reset.com, which has some helpful info on CSS resets (shocking) for us poor n00bs who need them ;).  [link](http://www.css-reset.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid a generic CSS reset, but use something like this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
    width: 60ex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px; /* it's best to have a little padding */
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* gets around varying border styles */
    border-radius: 4px /* optional; for newer browsers */
}
```

As long as you're in standards mode and not quirks mode this should work fine for most browsers.

Notes:

- The attribute selectors - `[type="text"]` - don't work in IE6 so you may wish to opt for a class name instead.
- You can't get all browsers to display form fields exactly the same way.
- Using ex as the unit, whilst a good idea, might not work well in a fixed-pixel width environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use pixel rather than EM or pct values. 60px = 60px across all browsers, regardless of base font size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party, but in case anyone runs into this and needs to use ex's for width, I finally got it to work.

Textareas by default use monospace for their font-family.  So, you'll need to override that.  This css worked for me:

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 2px groove;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 35ex;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxahau9c/

Answer (score -1):

padding left and right 0px

Comment: Please provide more context for your answer.