# Text Field Taking Up Entire Row

Tags: css, html

I have a text field that is expanding the entire horizontal distance to the window which I don't want. I've tried restricting the size in any way that I can think of:

```
<input class="searchField" id="searchBar" style="size:10;" type="text" size="10px" value="Search Here" />
```

with CSS:

```
#searchBar input
{
    width:10px;
}

.searchField 
{
    size:10px;
}
```

It is likely that somewhere the other HTML/CSS code is causing it to expand all the way. My question: is there a way to override it so that locally at that input text field, I can have my own size, say 10 pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just incase it is targeted with a different width property elsewhere, use

```
.searchField { width:10px !important; }
```

Comment: Just so you know. If this fixes it, it's probably a problem with your CSS. Search your CSS file(s) for the original declaration (.searchField) and try to fix the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `width` property.

```
#searchBar { 
  width: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have put this in instead, I've tried width with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the width css property.

```
.searchField 
{
     max-width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of a `size` CSS property. Do you mean `width` (say `width: 10px`)?

Answer (score 0):

'size' is an invalid css property. Use width instead. Give your input a width of 100px for example, 10px is way too little. You may also want to have a look at [Input size vs width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480588/input-size-vs-width)