# Specify width of 3 chars for an html input text

Tags: html, css

How would I create an `HTML` text box that exactly 3 characters can fit into it?
I found this online:  `<input type="text" style="width: 10px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black"/>`
It creates a text box with width of 10px. I could use this but I was wondering if we could explicitely set for 3 chars width instead of "playing" with pixels,

Comment: Some interesting discussion about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1480588/589985) - the `size` attribute should work, but it'll be overridden by any CSS that might apply.  And it may not be consistent across browsers...

Comment: @XavierHolt:`size` is for the max acceptable input. I am interested in width

Comment: @Craytus - Actually, `size` affects width here - `maxlength` is the one that controls the max number of characters.  Check out [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) for a more thorough description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not reliably, since l and W have very different widths.

However, if you set the font to `monospace`, that helps. Then, you should be able to set `size="3"` on the input element, and in theory it should be exactly three characters wide.

Comment: This generally works in practice, too. And the font does not need to be set to `monospace` (the browser-dependent generic monospace font) but to *some* monospace font, e.g. with `font-family: Consolas, Lucida Console, monospace`.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `ch` metric.

```
width: 3ch;
```

Make sure your `box-sizing` property is set to `content-box` if you're changing left and/or right padding.