# Where can I change the form text box size?

Tags: symfony

I make form in `Controller` like this below.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($row)
->add('comment',null,array('label' => 'input comment'))
```

then in the twig file...

```
{{form_widget(form.commentToMutor)}}
```

It shows text input box,but it is too small.

How to change size of `TextBox`

Comment: I guess you can change the text box size with css

Comment: IMHO `<input type="text">` size is specified not via `width` but via `size` attribute.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Extending @manseuk 's answer (I don't have enough reputation to post a comment), you can also specify the html style attribute inside the form builder, if you preffer:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($row)
   ->add('comment', null, array(
           'label' => 'input comment', 
           'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 200px')
          )
   );
```

**Edited** from `html attribute for width` to `html style attribute`.

Comment: i think it is `size` attribute, not `width` you meant? Because `<input type="text" size="128">` works but `<input type="text" width="128">` does not.

Comment: I think you're right, it appears not to work. It should be something like `'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 200px')` despite it seems to work for the user I answered. In addition, you maybe wanna read the difference between `size` and `width`, just in case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480588/input-size-vs-width

Comment: surely  `width` should be part of the `style` attribute, so `'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 200px'` surely should work. However your original answer states: `'attr' => array('width' => '200')` which would simply produce html code `<input type="text" width="128">` where `width` attribute is ignored because it doesn't make sense. I think the person who accepted the answer may have tweaked your code (to `style` or `size`), but simply accepted the answer as it is. So I wonder if believe it is worthwhile to edit the answer?

Answer (score 7):

You could add a `class` to the form field :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($row)
   ->add('comment',null,array(
           'label' => 'input comment', 
           'attr' => array('class' => 'myclass')
          )
   );
```

and then create the CSS relevant to that class :

```
.myclass {
   width: 200px;
}
```

[Docs for the `attr` attribute here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr)

Answer (score 3):

Or in the twig file:

```
{# Define CSS class and call #}
{{ form_widget(form.commentToMutor, { 'attr': {'class': 'myclass'} }) }}

{# ... or enter width directly #}
{{ form_widget(form.commentToMutor, { 'attr': {'style': 'width: 200px'} }) }}
```

[More here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the width directly did not work for me. I  had to set it through the style. Of course this is an easy fix, the correct way is to use a css class like others have suggested.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($row)
   ->add('comment', null, array(
           'label' => 'input comment', 
           'attr' => array('style' => 'width:200px')
          )
   );
```