# How to make all `<input` text field to size of 50?

Tags: html, css

How to make all `<input` text field to size of 50 ?

I have been using

```
<table>
<tr>
...
<input type="text" size="50" ...>
```

But this is too much typing .
How can I include this style to `<style>`

i tried

```
<style>
input 
{
size:100
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can affect the `width` but not the `size`. You could have `javascript` or `jQuery` come back through on page load and do it, though.

In `jQuery` you could use:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    // Document is ready / loaded
    $("input").attr("size", "60");
  });
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this question:
[Input size vs width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480588/input-size-vs-width)

I think that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The `size` attribute specifies the suggested visible width of the control, using “average” width characters. This is a vague concept and implemented inconsistently in browsers. There is no way to replicated this behavior in CSS.

What comes closest is using the [`ch` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), which formally denotes the width of the digit “0” but can in practice be taken as an approximation of “average-width character”. So you could set

```
 input { width: 50ch }
```

In practice, there is also the problem that the `ch` unit is not supported by many browsers still in use (mainly IE 8 and older).

The conclusion is that you should keep using the `size` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`Size` is an attribute not `Style` component. So you cannot set it with CSS. Instead you can use `width` -

```
<style>
input 
{
    width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

just use a **trial and error** way to determine how much is it in `px` for size `50` then use it as the width.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to define in the style only text inputs. Also 311px is the size of a size="50" text input

```
<style>
input[type=text] {
width:311px;
}
</style>
```