Make <input> take only the width it need for containing its content
I can't seem to successfully make the <input> element not take a lot of space, what can I do to make the <input> take only the width it need for containing its content - growing with the content?
For example:
<input type="number" value="1" readOnly />

would take much more the needed space.
I tried some stuff like:
input {
  width: fit-content;
}

and more.
Note: I don't want a solution that requires flex (because it need to apply in more cases), or other case-specific methods. Also it should be only css.

flexbox is CSS. why can't you use Flexbox? How should you know the length of any content before it is typed in? Should the input grow with the content?

Yes, the input should grow with the content. My mistake for not pointing this out.

No, this is not possible. Firstly, input have a default width of, I think, 125px. The only methods of changing that are by width or the size attribute. Neither of those allow an input to size to it's content especially a changing content. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409621/can-css-over-rule-html-input-size-declarations
