# Firefox ignores size of html <input> element

Tags: html, firefox

Using Firefox Quantum 60.5.1esr (64-bit) in OpenSuse 15.0

This code

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<body>
<p>


<label for='product_quantity'>Quantity:</label>
<input id='product_quantity' name='product[quantity]' size='50' type='text' value='9999999999999999999999999'>


<br>

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Produces a big text box in Opera or Chome, filled with a lot o 9s, but in Firefox and Seamonkey it produces a little text box, so little I can't see any number.

The same version of firefox in other computer with Opensuse 42.3 works fine (show the big text box).

why?

regards

Comment: Fixed width is normally frowned on these days anyway because it does not foster responsive design.  You should probably give  input a % based width anyway via CSS or a style tag so that it can adjust to it's container.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480588/input-size-vs-width

Comment: Note that you are in "quirks mode" and using a doctype no one should be using since 1999 at least.

Answer (score 0):

Give the width in %. It may help you.This elements are browser specific and different browser respond differently to all this elements and attributes.
You can go through w3schools document for it.
[Here it is](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Comment: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) (MDN) is a far more reliable resource than W3Fools. (*w3schools is not related to the w3c group who look after the internet standards*)

Comment: Yes i truely agree you may refer both.