# How to standardize the height of a select box between Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: css

Check out http://demo.neeraj.name/admin_data in both Chrome and Firefox. In Firefox the select box has large height. In Chrome the height of select box is very small.

How do I make the select box of chrome and safari look like the select drop down of Firefox?

Comment: try [jqTranform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/). you'll have more control over the form elements.

Comment: Please consider changing the correct answer as the one with the highest votes is far more practical.

Comment: This question is no longer real. Because you are referring to things that no longer exist. It would have been better if you copied the HTML, CSS and other relevant things into the question text...

Comment: Makes sure to scroll down to the very bottom. Unfortunately the best answer is 2nd from last.

Answer (score 147):

I've run into this problem before

Setting the height of the select element works fine on webkit in Windows, but fails on webkit on a Mac.

If you set the css attribute

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
```

It will allow the height to work properly on a Mac, but it creates this weird black border on windows.  You can adjust the border by setting the css border property, but that changes the look on all browsers that let you style select borders, not just webkit.

At this point, i gave up, but hopefully that is a good starting point if you want to investigate further.

Comment: This should be the right answer.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Oh, and to set this just for Chrome, use the following media query to wrap the statement:

`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
 }
}`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `-webkit-appearance: none` works, but then on Chrome it doesn't show the text in the dropdown (for both the options and the selected option).

Comment: I am using opacity: 0 and my own graphic on top, so this is perfect +1

Comment: how do you `set the css attribute` ?

Comment: thanks @marcamillion .. your comment helped me.

Answer (score 34):

Increase the `line-height`.

Comment: This stopped working in Mac Chrome 30.0.1599.69

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!!!! Suffered for hours with this crap... Now I just need to set the things font for the selected item

Comment: @travis-146 A workaround to this is to add `-webkit-select-appearance: none` and then style it how you want. Downside to that approach is that you have to completely style it yourself (add arrows, etc).

Comment: -1 line-height has no effect on FF Ubuntu 12. Increasing the font-size worked.

Answer (score 17):

*height* will not work on Safari unless you also have a *background* set.  If you set a background you may lose the drop down arrows in the windows version of Safari.  Again form styling seems to be wrought with issues.

Comment: Setting 'background: none' seems sufficient to make Chrome and Safari respect the height property for select boxes on OSX. Still seems like a hack though. The jQuery combobox solution is probably better long-term.

Comment: @antonm: I'm not sure how well jQuery combobox works on mobile.

Comment: @antonm doesn't most of CSS seem like a hack? :) I've accepted the feeling that I'm doing something the wrong way when I'm writing CSS

Answer (score 9):

@Chi's answer is correct.  Another quick hack is to add a border CSS style:

select {
  border: 1px solid #CCC
}

This both triggers the -webkit-appearance: menulist-button property with the added benefit of removing the ugly black border :).

Comment: Same effect as `-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;`

Comment: Totally works.  Chrome, Safari, Firefox.  FTW!

Answer (score 8):

use css border property. make the select border to none or 0. **border:none**; showing perfectly in chrome and safari in mac os

Comment: Setting the `border:none;` or `border:1px solid #ccc;` seems to turn on the ability to modify the font properties of the input for Mac Chrome/Safari. Strange.

Comment: Yep I wrote a blog post on it, just add border and you can change the height, font etc. http://webstori.es/normalise-select-html-tags-in-windows-and-mac/

Comment: This also works on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.102 on MacOS similar to Chi's answer with the webkit menu list option.

Answer (score 2):

I used jQuery [combobox](http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/jquery/ddcombobox) for this.

With this, you can set the height of the necessary CSS classes to the height you need your select box to be.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it to a similar link.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the font-size to help with the height as well. I think that Safari mac show up to 16px font-size. At least gets a larger click region.

Answer (score 1):

Use ***line-height*** for safari its working.

Answer (score 0):

Sample page works Google Chrome 4 and Safari 4

Comment: Works as in looks the same as in Firefox? Not for me.

Comment: Google Chrome - http://twitpic.com/1cc62p
Safari - http://twitpic.com/1cc664

Comment: you can set the `select` tag class to `btn` then change it's height, using `css`, that's how I solved it(on mac)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the height property. line-height worked in Safari on Windows, but not on Mac. height worked on both.

Comment: I have the same problem and the Chrome on Mac just doen't want to change it