# How do I apply padding within a select dropdown box?

Tags: html, css

I have two types of input. A `select` dropdown box, and a regular `input`.

On the `input`, I have added a `padding: 10px;` that makes it look big.

The issue is once I put the select box beside it, they are both different heights.

How do I either apply the padding to the select, or make it the same height as the `input`.

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/5hxNu/1/).

**Edit 1**

This is how it looks to me: [image]

Comment: Isn't it working? Well either a) i dont understand your question or B) It work on chrome.

Comment: It's not working. The select box is smaller - in physical size - than the input text field. I am using Chrome on OS X and it looks smaller to me. Let me update the question with a screenshot of how it looks to me.

Comment: it must certainly be because of the OS since input arent the same, well i can tell you it work on Windows8 + lastest chrome.

Comment: it works fine on ubuntu  and windows 7 for me.

Comment: Works fine in SeaMonkey 2.17, Chrome 26 and Firefox 20 under Fedora 17. If this is really important to you, consider using jQueriUI, to make your controls all look alike.

Comment: OSX won't style a select box like Windows.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none` at least to the `<select>` but possibly to both.  OSX really wants their controls to look apple-y

Comment: Anyway to get this to not look weird on OS X? By weird, I mean 'plain'?

Comment: @marcamillion there may be other styles being applied; you can look at the "Computed Styles + Show Inherited" to see what's being applied.  I don't have OS-X available right now, so I can't tell

Comment: Hey @ExplosionPills - any ideas as to why this makes the text disappear? It is the highest rank style too - so there is no other style that it is inheriting that is causing that, that I can see. Here are more details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631801/why-does-using-webkit-appearance-none-on-a-select-option-in-osx-make-the-tex

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the select element:

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
```

Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075922