# html-select height increase in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, html-select

How to increse the height of the select combo box in the IE6 browser where by default it is showing 11 items in the list.Please can any give the solution for it

Answer (score 1):

The height of a select list in IE is controlled by the browser.

[Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

You have no ability to change the height at all

Comment: Thnaks for your response,What is the solution if i want to display more elements in the list of dropdown when it is triggered without using scrollbar

Comment: There is no solution.  The browser fully controls how many are seen.  11 in IE5.0,5.5, 30 in IE6,7,8 and In IE, if there are no options, a stupidly high list of 11 blanks entries. If you want to have a different visual drop-down, you'll need to roll your own using JavaScript and or your favorite JS Library.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you here: [Setting the height of a SELECT in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490036/setting-the-height-of-a-select-in-ie/4877544#4877544)
look for my post