# Increass the height of selection box

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the height of a SELECT in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490036/setting-the-height-of-a-select-in-ie)

I need to increase the height of selection box in IE7.
In chrome and firefox, wok fine. But in ie7 the section box height is small. I try to set the `font-size` as `30px`. The height is increased but the text is so large.

Here I attached the image

[image]

How I `increase` the `height` of selection box `with out` set the `font-size`.
I am waiting for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is noway of doing it in IE., unless you use a custom made select box like

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: +1 for suggesting Chosen. That plugin is a miracle worker.

Answer (score 1):

What about giving it some padding? Try this CSS

```
select {padding:20px 0px;}
```

Or if you want the text to be on top then give a padding to the bottom

```
select {padding-bottom:20px;}
```

I hope padding works in IE ;)

**Note:** The selection arrow doesn't change it's height, sadly. You might try some jQuery solution.

Comment: Hi Deepak, Its did not work. I tried both of this. any other solution?

Comment: Padding for `<select>` doesn't work in IE ? Hmm, that's sad. Last solution is using a jQuery selection widget.