# Define height of select box

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with select box height. Is it possible to make select list shorter with css property or other way?
see attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing you can do with plain CSS to make it shorter. You'll probably need to look at a JS solution.

Comment: Setting a height would fix it but IE will ignore it. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490036/setting-the-height-of-a-select-in-ie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this trick:

```
<select onmouseover="this.size=10;" onmouseout="this.size=1;">
```

See the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/h9SKM/

Answer (score -1):

What I suggested earlier does not work if you dont have multiple set on the select element makeing it a not general way of solving the problem.

AFAIK, there is no CSS-approach to this problem. You have to use Javscript,