# how to descrease the height of select box .It is loading with large number of records

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to descrease the height of select box .It is loading with large number of records like 200 or three hundered.I want to make it smaller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806237/define-height-of-select-box

Comment: use the autocomplete or bootstrap to make the field as searchable. this will help.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with pure CSS, you have to check some other solutions, like javascript or select that is build on divs.

TRY: 
`<select onmouseclick="this.size=10;" onmouseout="this.size=1;"> ... </select>`