# IE7 - using a div to mask a select - select's height is being ignored, the dropdown's position is too high, over the text

Tags: html, css

I use a div as a mask, set it to position absolute and z-index 1. Over it, using z-index 2 and position relative, I have placed a select.

I'm struggling with this code in IE7, basically, IE7 ignores the height of the select - thus moving the dropdown list too high, over the mask's text.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddany30/BAPsE/).

```
<div class="select-container">
    <div class="mask">This is the mask</div>
    <select>
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
    </select>
</div><!-- /select_container -->


.mask {
    height: 32px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid grey
}

.select-container select {
    height: 34px;
    width: 212px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    opacity: -1;
    filter: alpha(opacity:-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, `select` elements don't accept set heights in IE7 (and various other browsers / versions). Here's a similar [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490036/setting-the-height-of-a-select-in-ie). Your best bet is use something else.

Comment: I'm leaving the question open, maybe there is a css hack, or something. Ty for the answer, it's a bit disappointing.